# how disable the quantity selector field on hitting checkbox in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am beginner on WordPress.
I want to get two things done on my WordPress site.

No 1: I want to make checkbox just with the word "Total"
No:2: When user would hit the checkbox, the quantity selector
must be disabled or diapered and only 1 item must be added into cart.

Please help me out, how can i do that.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2):

if you want that customer will order only one quantity of product then you can do one thing is using woo-commerce

**=>** in **product menu** select add new product or edit nay product and GOTO **product data** below **Editor** and select **inventory tab** from that.

**=>** and select **sold individually** checkbox so this allow only one quantity for sell.

so you don't need to write any code for that.

and let me know if you want to write code for that.

I Hope this will work for you perfectly.

Thanks.

**Edited :-**
May i hope you got your answer this time
 /**@ Remove in all product type*/

```
function custom_remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {return true;}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually','custom_remove_all_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
```

===================================

**Edit for particular product**

```
/**
* @Hide from different product type group
*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'baztro_wc_remove_all_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
function baztro_wc_remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {
switch ( $product->product_type ) :
case "variable":
return true;
break;
case "grouped":
return true;
break;
case "external":
return true;
break;
default: // simple product type
return true;
break;
endswitch;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i already knew it. 
What i' m asking for , please follow my question. 
what i wanted to do , i have provided you detailed image. 

I need to write code to first of all create checkbox and then based on behavior of checkbox , quantity selector would be showing up or not .

Hope you got my point

Comment: No, this would apply on all. I want this to apply but when somebody is marking the checkbkx,

Comment: @zeeshanhaider bro, for that you have to get checkbox value and base on that value you perform this action,

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
function add_checkbox_before_addtocart_quantity() { 
?>
    <div style="display:block; clear:both;"><input type="checkbox" id="totalcheck" name="subscribe" value="totalcheck"><label for="totalcheck"> Total</label></div>
    <script>
    (function( $ ) {
        $('input#totalcheck').change(function () {
                if(this.checked) {
                    // Set quantity to 1
                    $("input.input-text.qty.text").val("1");
                    // Hide quantity box
                    $(".quantity").hide();
                }else{
                    // Show quantity box if total is not checked
                    $(".quantity").show();
                }
         });
    })( jQuery );
    </script>
<?php
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'add_checkbox_before_addtocart_quantity', 10 );
```